# ActionView Helper set attribute name for input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

How set attribute name to form input ?

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :statuslist_id %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :statuslist_id %>
  </div>
```

HTML result:

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="act_statuslist_id">Statuslist</label><br>
    <input id="act_statuslist_id" name="act[statuslist_id]" type="number" />
  </div>
```

I need

```
 <input id="act_statuslist_id" name="act[statuslist_id][]" type="number" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what your goal is, perhaps you should check out 'fields_for.'  But you can achieve what you want like this:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= label_tag :act_statuslist_id %><br>
  <%= number_field_tag "act[status_list_id][]" %>
</div>
```

Depending on your intent and what model/record the form is based off you might want to do something different.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the `name` you want:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :status_list_id %><br>
  <%= f.number_field :status_list_id, name: 'act[status_list_id][]' %>
</div>
```